# How to recreate the animation function from the specified graph?

Tags: javascript, function, animation, math

I'm trying to find a math function for animating, but so far without success. There must be some very simple solution for this, but I'm a bit confused. I need to get the value of a function like in the example image

[image: the example image].

```
[A1,B1] - range of possible argument value
[A,C]   - range of function values
D       - the value of the argument for which the function shows the minimum value
```

What type of functions is this? I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I see is piecewise curve: 2 quadratic + 2 line for example something like this in C++:

```cpp
float x0,x1,x2,y0,y1,y2; // set these to your curve edge points
float fx(float x) // this returns y for any x
    {
    if (x<=x0) return y0;
    if (x<=x1)
        {
        float a=(x-x1)/(x1-x0);
        return y1+a*a*(y0-y1);
        }
    if (x<=x2)
        {
        float a=(x-x1)/(x2-x1);
        return y1+a*a*(y2-y1);
        }
    return y2;
    }
```

And here how it looks like:

[image: preview]

Comment: Changed the graph a bit. It meant the projection onto the x-axis of points A and B

Comment: This is not a motion animation. In fact, I need to get values for any points on this graph in order to resize the objects I need. For now I'm leaning towards the normal distribution.

Comment: @Rox had some time mood for this so I tried it in C++ see my answer for the result. Just configure the 3 input points to your liking ...